# Проблема с использованием Identity Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

в моем проекте который я пишу на Asp.net web api (https://github.com/NeTBoyBot/SolarLabProject)
При попытке перехода с чистого Identity на Identity Server возникла небольшая проблема.
При обращении к HttpContextAccessor-у и попытке получить у него клеймы, он возвращает мне их пустыми. На чистой версии айдентити при обращении к нему же, все прекрасно. На гите есть две ветки на master ветке чистый айдентити, на Identity ветке моя безуспешная попытка имплементации данного функционала.

```
public async Task<string> Login(LoginUserRequest userLogin, CancellationToken cancellation)
    {
        var existingUser = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(userLogin.Email);
        if (existingUser == null)
            throw new Exception($"Пользователь с email '{userLogin.Email}' не существует");

        var checkPass = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(existingUser, userLogin.Password);
        if (!checkPass)
            throw new Exception("Неверная почта или пароль");

        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, existingUser.Id.ToString()),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, existingUser.UserName)
        };

        var userRole = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(existingUser);
        claims.AddRange(userRole.Select(role => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role)));


        var secretKey = _configuration["Jwt:Key"];

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken
            (
            claims: claims,
            expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
            notBefore: DateTime.UtcNow,
            signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(
                new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey)),
                SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
           );

        var result = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

        if (cancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
            throw new OperationCanceledException();


        return result;
    }

public async Task<InfoUserResponse> GetCurrentUser(CancellationToken cancellation)
    {
        var claim = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims;
        var claimId = claim.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
        //var claimId = _claimAccessor.UserId;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(claimId))
            return null;

        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(claimId);

        if (user == null)
            throw new Exception($"Не найдент пользователь с идентификаторром {claimId}");

        var userResponse = _mapper.Map<InfoUserResponse>(user);
        userResponse.Id = Guid.Parse(user.Id);
        userResponse.Role = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
        return userResponse;


    }
```

Код регистрации IHttpContextAccessor-a

```
builder.Services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(
options =>
{

```
    var secretKey = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"];

    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateActor = false,
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey))
    };
});
```

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

Comment: По поводу перехода с .NET Identity на Duende Identity Server есть [плейлист](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLePGPxR0FDm9oltBczmL_0S3zK5GbJ1rX), может быть вам поможет.